# Neo4j syntaxerror when loading in CSV data

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, syntax-error, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to load in data from the DEA on drug transactions and when I enter my query into my cypher terminal I get an error.

I entered the following query:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TruncatedDEA.csv' AS line,
  'MERGE (buyer:Buyer {BUYER_DEA_NO: line.BUYER_DEA_NO})
   ON CREATE SET 
     buyer.BUYER_BUS_ACT = line.BUYER_BUS_ACT,
     buyer.BUYER_NAME = line.BUYER_NAME,
     buyer.BUYER_ADDL_CO_INFO = line.BUYER_ADDL_CO_INFO,
     buyer.BUYER_ADDRESS1 = line.BUYER_ADDRESS1,
     buyer.BUYER_ADDRESS2 = line.BUYER_ADDRESS2,
     buyer.BUYER_CITY = line.BUYER_CITY,
     buyer.BUYER_STATE = line.BUYER_STATE,
     buyer.BUYER_ZIP = line.BUYER_ZIP,
     buyer.BUYER_COUNTY = line.BUYER_COUNTY;

   MERGE (reporter:Reporter {REPORTER_DEA_NO: line.REPORTER_DEA_NO})
   ON CREATE SET 
     reporter.REPORTER_BUS_ACT = line.REPORTER_BUS_ACT,
     reporter.REPORTER_NAME = line.REPORTER_NAME,
     reporter.REPORTER_ADDL_CO_INFO = line.REPORTER_ADDL_CO_INFO,
     reporter.REPORTER_ADDRESS1 = line.REPORTER_ADDRESS1,
     reporter.REPORTER_ADDRESS2 = line.REPORTER_ADDRESS2,
     reporter.REPORTER_CITY = line.REPORTER_CITY,
     reporter.REPORTER_STATE = line.REPORTER_STATE,
     reporter.REPORTER_ZIP = line.REPORTER_ZIP,
     reporter.REPORTER_COUNTY = line.REPORTER_COUNTY,
     reporter.Reporter_family = line.Reporter_family;

   MERGE (drug:Drug {DRUG_CODE: line.DRUG_CODE})
   ON CREATE SET 
     drug.DRUG_NAME = line.DRUG_NAME,
     drug.Product_Name = line.Product_Name,
     drug.Ingredient_Name = line.Ingredient_Name,
     drug.Measure = line.Measure,
     drug.MME_Conversion_Factor = line.MME_Conversion_Factor,
     drug.Combined_Labeler_Name = line.Combined_Labeler_Name,
     drug.dos_str = line.dos_str,
     drug.MME = line.MME;

   MATCH (buyer:Buyer {BUYER_DEA_NO: line.BUYER_DEA_NO})
   MATCH (reporter:Reporter {REPORTER_DEA_NO: line.REPORTER_DEA_NO})
   MATCH (drug:Drug {DRUG_CODE: line.DRUG_CODE})
   MERGE (transaction:Transaction {TRANSACTION_ID: line.TRANSACTION_ID})
   ON CREATE SET 
     transaction.TRANSACTION_CODE = line.TRANSACTION_CODE,
     transaction.QUANTITY = line.QUANTITY,
     transaction.UNIT = line.UNIT,
     transaction.ACTION_INDICATOR = line.ACTION_INDICATOR,
     transaction.ORDER_FORM_NO = line.ORDER_FORM_NO,
     transaction.CORRECTION_NO = line.CORRECTION_NO,
     transaction.TRANSACTION_DATE = line.TRANSACTION_DATE;

   MERGE (buyer)-[:BOUGHT]->(transaction)
   MERGE (reporter)-[:REPORTED]->(transaction)
   MERGE (drug)-[:CONTAINS]->(transaction);',
   {batchSize:1000, parallel:false}
);
```

The error reads as follows:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Invalid input 'CSV': expected
  "!="
  "%"
  ")"
  "*"
  "+"
  ","
  "-"
  "."
  "/"
  ":"
  "<"
  "<="
  "<>"
  "="
  "=~"
  ">"
  ">="
  "AND"
  "CONTAINS"
  "ENDS"
  "IN"
  "IS"
  "OR"
  "STARTS"
  "XOR"
  "["
  "^" (line 2, column 8 (offset: 35))
"  LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TruncatedDEA.csv' AS line,"
        ^
```

What did I do wrong with my code? I already checked the csv file, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the first parameter (called cypher iterate) in quotes and RETURN each line (or row) by batch size. Then it will be passed to the cypher action (or query) on the second parameter in 1k per batch.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///TruncatedDEA.csv" AS line RETURN line',
  '<put your query here>',
   {batchSize:1000, parallel:false}
);
```

See example here:
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/import/load-csv/#_transaction_batching